# google plus, do I link the main page or sub pages

Tags: google-plus

I have a page that consist of a daily updated front page with every day archived in a sub-page. The sub pages are either a funny picture or a joke. The pictures and jokes have a like and share option (for facebook, stumbleupon and pinit for instance), which obviously link to the picture or joke in question. I'm puzzled what to do with the google plus button though.

What is good pratice? Link to google plus with the link straight to the picture (sub-page) or set it up to share the main page?

so this:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" //...// data-href="http://www.amazingjokes.com/"></div>
```

or this:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" //...// data-href="http://www.amazingjokes.com/?view=img&date=2013-06-16"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would concur with what Scarygami says, but also add that this may be a scenario where an [interactive post/share](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) might be appropriate as well. You could have the shared info go to your top level page, and a "Visit" button go to the more specific sub-page.

Answer (score 3):

Really depends on what you want to do.

Linking the +1-Button to your main page will have an accumulated count for your page, while linking it to the picture will have a count per-picture which I think would make more sense in your scenario.

Of course you can have an additional +1-Button for your main page so people can show their appreciation for your page in general. If you have a Google+ Page associated with your site you could also use a [page badge](https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/) for this.